# Submitting form hidden field or canvas with with javascript and.or ajax?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, canvas, fabricjs

I have a canvas I would like to save along with a form submit.  The way I currently have seems to only be saving a blank canvas.  Although, from the code you will see, I am able to save the canvas successfully with a save button...

Code:

View:

```
...
<%= ff.hidden_field :print_file, id: "canvascontent" %>
<a id="lnkDownload" title="Save">Save</a> #this is the button that saves form
<canvas id="fCanvas"></canvas>
...
<%= f.submit "Save" %>
```

Javascript:

```
#canvas/fabric js code here
...
#save button code
var imageSaver = document.getElementById('lnkDownload');
imageSaver.addEventListener('click', saveImage, false);

function saveImage(e) {
   this.href = canvas.toDataURL({
      format: 'png',
      quality: 0.8
   });
   this.download = 'saved_image.png'
};

#form submit save attached to hidden field
var url = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
$("#canvascontent").val(url);
```

What the hidden_field passes through on form submit is a base64 image.  Unfortunately, it's blank.

Is there a way I can save the canvas on form submit that will pass the canvas through the same way the save button does?

I can only assume the canvas data is being left behind before it's able to be sent to the form submit.

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

> Attempts to triggering `toDataURL`:

```
<a id="setDownload" title="Save">Save</a>

var imageSetter = document.getElementById('setDownload');
   imageSetter.addEventListener('click', setImage, false);
   function setImage(e) {
      this.href = canvas.toDataURL({
          format: 'png',
          quality: 0.8
      });
   $("#canvascontent").val(this.href);
};
```

This is in attempt to "set" the image.  When i click the setDownload , IT WORKS and it saves the canvas how i want with the form submit.  It will successfully get into my model

Now, I try calling the imageSetter like so...

The `updateImage` function adds images to the canvas successfully.

```
function updateImage(imageURL){
    fabric.Image.fromURL(imageURL, function(img) {
        #canvas_image_rendering_code
        }, {crossOrigin: 'anonymous'});
    var url = canvas.toDataURL({
        format: 'png',
        quality: 0.8
    });
    setImage();
};
```

With this, the saved image is still blank...for some reason setImage isn't being called? or so i thought...

I also thought maybe the canvas wasn't loaded so I tried `setTimeout(setImage(), 3000);` which isn't ideal even if it works but wanted to see.

Then i thought, is it even being called?

So i set `setImage` as an alert to se if it's calling it

```
function setImage() {
  alert("Hello");
}
```

And it IS being called..the alert pops up when i choose an image for the canvas

How can I call the `setImage` function from within that function and have it work the same way as when i click `setDownload`?

What's the story of why this happens?

Keys:

1. Saves canvas on form submit when i click `setDownload` link href.
2. calling `setImage` function within `updateImage` function works with alert example, but not with setting the image with toDataURL.

Comment: When/how are you calling that code that updates the hidden field?

Comment: I figured the `var url = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')` would be simply converting the canvas and anything that's in it should be attached to that value?  toDataURL is the method of saving what's currently in the canvas.  So should i be creating some sort of function similar to the button?

Comment: I repeat my question, when/who do you call that code that sets the value on the hidden field? you say "form submit save attached to hidden field" but I see no form `submit` or submit button `click` event listener on your code.

Comment: I have a form submit button only.  I was assuming the value of the hidden field would constantly be saving the canvas.

Comment: You have to set the hidden field value, it doesn't set the canvas content as the value automatically, you have to set it before submitting the form.

Comment: I made some update and attempts.  Any pointers to my updated OP? @arieljuod

Comment: What does `setImage` do? set it inside the fabrijs's fromURL callback function (where you have #canvas_image_rendering_code). The way you have it now, you are calling the function before the img is loaded.

Comment: To my knowledge, toDataURL takes the current canvas and turns it into a base64.

Comment: I put it inside but still blank images.  Only way working is with the `setDownload` button.. I want to immulate that but not by clicking a button, just by when the image is added.  I can also try doign a mouseover trigger for the body of the canvas (and.or around the canvas) but i am afraid that may be overkill